# sed search and replace a string with its sub string value

Tags: unix, sed

I have a Create Table Script ( External Table). I want to replace the table name as EXT_[First 27 characters of the original table]

**Sample I/P file**

```
CREATE TABLE "P12345678912345678912345678912"
(
  "PARTITION_KEY" VARCHAR2(12),
  "ID" VARCHAR2(100),
  "STRESS_TESTING_SCENARIO_ID" VARCHAR2(100),
  "TRANCHE_COLLATERAL_TYPE" VARCHAR2(20),
  "TRANCHE_GUARANTEE_TYPE" VARCHAR2(20),
  "BS_TYPE" VARCHAR2(3),
  "CONTRACT_REFERENCE" VARCHAR2(50),
```

**Expected O/p**

```
CREATE TABLE "EXT_P12345678912345678912345678"
(
  "PARTITION_KEY" VARCHAR2(12),
  "ID" VARCHAR2(100),
  "STRESS_TESTING_SCENARIO_ID" VARCHAR2(100),
  "TRANCHE_COLLATERAL_TYPE" VARCHAR2(20),
  "TRANCHE_GUARANTEE_TYPE" VARCHAR2(20),
  "BS_TYPE" VARCHAR2(3),
  "CONTRACT_REFERENCE" VARCHAR2(50),
```

The script needs to work on both Linux and Solaris.

Comment: Please do use the [edit] button to fix the code in your question. currently it is quite difficult to understand. Also, do not use capital letters in the title since it looks like YOU ARE SHOUTING

Comment: @fedorqui: Noted! Will be careful the next time. Thanks!

Comment: this `sed 's/CREATE TABLE "/CREATE TABLE "EXT_/g'`

Comment: `sed 's/./\l&/g' <<< yourTitle`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Thanks! This works  but the only problem is that the final table name in the script can become more than 30 char. Also I was wondering if there is a way to implement the requirement .

Comment: **Found a way but still looking for other options**
>`sed '/CREATE/s/\(.*\) "\(..........................\).*"/\1 EXT_\2/g'`

Answer (score 0):

this awk one-liner works for your example:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='"' '/CREATE TABLE/{$2=substr($2,1,27);sub("^","EXT_",$2)}7' file
```

Comment: Thanks! However if you find a way to do it using SED do let me know !

Comment: @Dipak why it is a sed-must task? sed has no built-in functions like substr(), you can somehow "count" via hold/pattern spaces, however it would be much more complicated.

Comment: It is not a must. What you said is absolutely true but still curious to see if there is a way out with SED.